# How to Make a Table Row Span the Width of the Largest Row?

Tags: c#, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently trying using Bootstrap to create a table that generated dynamically using my c# code.  The issue however is that some columns contain more table data tags than the others, so the table end's up having rows that are longer than the other.

I would like to be able to have all of the row's match the length of the largest row, and fill the empty spots with blank spaces.

Here is an example of what I am trying:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>john@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mary</td>
      <td>Moe</td>
      <td>mary@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>July</td>
      <td>Dooley</td>
      <td>july@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>incomplete</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The HTML table structure should always contains equal amounts of cells per row.
If you are generating the html through C#, you should fill in the missing blank elements.

The last TR should look like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>incomplete</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

You can also use & nbsp; inside the empty td tags.

Another option is to make the td cover multiple cells using colspan:

```
<td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
```

Would cover 3 cells instead of 1.

Comment: Ah okay!  I was wondering if there would be a tag or something to do so.  I'll make sure to include a counter within my c# code to add empty elements for each tag.